# Unable to use JSON-SerDe to create table in Hive

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

Ive downloaded and configured 
 https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde 
to import JSON logs in Hive.
However creating a table using the example given in the readme

```
CREATE TABLE json_test1 (
    one boolean,
    three array<string>,
    two double,
    four string )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

is giving me the following error

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.AbstractPrimitiveJavaObjectInspector.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/objectinspector/primitive/PrimitiveObjectInspectorUtils$PrimitiveTypeEntry;)V
```

I have setup and tested hive and even imported json logs using get_json_object and json_tuple without a problem. I have been on for hours now but cant find a solution.

Adding
Im using hadoop 2.2.0 and hive 0.13

Comment: Did you add the Serde to `classpath`?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `Serde jar` file to `$HIVE_HOME/lib`. That should take care of the issue.

Comment: done that too and additionally also used 'add jar ...' in .hiverc file

Comment: I would expect that workaround to apply to Hive-.11 and Hive-.12, but not to Hive-.13 which includes the fix for [HIVE-6670](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6670).